# Problema com a lógica do zipfile com Python

Tags: python, xml, arquivo-zip, path

Estou tentando fazer um script com python para zipar arquivos xls. Eu consegui fazer com que ele entre dentro diretório e está adicionando tudo dentro de um arquivo `.zip`. Porem eu queria que ele percorresse todos os subdiretórios e consiga trazer somente os arquivos .xls e não as pastas com os arquivos.

Ex:

O path seria esse:

> C:/folder/subfolder/201803

Dentro do path tenho pastas númeradas, ex:

> C:/folder/subfolder/201803/01
>
> C:/folder/subfolder/201803/02

e dentro dessas pastas tenho os arquivos .xls.

```
xmlzip = zipfile.ZipFile(pathfile, 'w')
for folder, subfolder, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xls'):
            xmlzip.write(os.path.join(folder, file), os.path.relpath(os.path.join(folder, file), path), compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
xmlzip.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para comprimir os arquivos sem a estrutura de diretórios, informe apenas o nome do arquivo no segundo parâmetro do método `xmlzip.write`:

```
xmlzip = zipfile.ZipFile(pathfile, 'w')
for folder, subfolder, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xls'):
            xmlzip.write(
                os.path.join(folder, file), 
                file, # AQUI => Informar apenas o nome do arquivo, sem o diretório
                compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
xmlzip.close()
```

Comment: Perfeito amigo. Muito obrigado, eu já tinha testado de várias formas e não tinha dado certo. Acho que faltou entender a estrutura mesmo. Muito obrigado mesmo.